# How can I Sort items in a view in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to sort the item I'm getting in my view and put them in a  different  divs  according to the category they belong 
In my table I have items the belong to different categories (cosmetics_perfumes, cosmetics_makeup …) 
Something like after I'm getting 
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
To sort it here in same way 
(I hope I'm clear )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in your view, then you can use a foreach statement for each of the categories.

```
<div id="perfumes">
    @foreach (var perfume in Model.Where(i => i.Category == "cosmetics_perfumes"))
    {
        <p>@perfume</p>  @*Display each item *@
    }
</div>
<div id="makeup">
    @foreach (var makeup in Model.Where(i => i.Category == "cosmetics_makeup"))
    {
        <p>@makeup</p>
    } 
</div>
```